# Could not resolve host : github.com error while cloning floodlight in git in mininet

Tags: git-clone, mininet

[Trying to install floodlight controller in mininet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ze4v7.png)

Answer (score 0):

DNS is not configured or there is no connectivity with the Internet.